# Examples of function the following three conditions

Tags: analysis, functions

Let function f:(0,∞)→(1,∞) satisfying the following conditions:

(i) f is nondecreasing;

(ii) for each sequence $({x_n})⊂(0,∞),lim_{n→∞}f(x_{n})=1$ if and only if $ lim_{n→∞}x_{n}=0⁺$;

(iii) there exists $r∈(0,1)$ and $k∈(0,∞]$ such that $lim_{x→0⁺}{\dfrac{f(x)-1}{x^{r}}}=k$.

can we find an example satisfying the above conditions except $e^{√t}$ and $e^{√te^{t}}$

Answer (score 0):

I like $f(x) = 1+k x^r$ for $k>0$ and $r>1$.

It's derivative is positive on $(0,\infty)$.  The only place it takes values near $1$ is near $x=0$, so it will not have a subsequence converging to $1$ anywhere else.  And it trivially satisfies the limit...  It's also a power law and not an exponential.